# I was trying to create a random password generator, using a list. but I got this error: IndexError: pop index out of range

Tags: python, list

**Here is the code.**
`

```
import random

pe = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
'!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '\*', '(', ')', '-', '\_', '=',
'+', '\[', ']', '{', '}', ';', ':', "'", '', '"', '', '|', '/',
'<', '>', ',', '.', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

letter_1 = random.randint(0, pe.__len__())
letter_2 = random.randint(0, pe.__len__())
letter_3 = random.randint(0, pe.__len__())
letter_4 = random.randint(0, pe.__len__())
letter_5 = random.randint(0, pe.__len__())
letter_6 = random.randint(0, pe.__len__())
letter_7 = random.randint(0, pe.__len__())
letter_8 = random.randint(0, pe.__len__())
letter_9 = random.randint(0, pe.__len__())
letter_10 = random.randint(0, pe.__len__())
letter_11 = random.randint(0, pe.__len__())
letter_12 = random.randint(0, pe.__len__())

print(pe.pop(letter_1)  + pe.pop(letter_2) + pe.pop(letter_3) + pe.pop(letter_4) +      pe.pop(letter_5) + pe.pop(letter_6) + pe.pop(letter_7) + pe.pop(letter_8) + pe.pop(letter_9) + pe.pop(letter_10) + pe.pop(letter_11) + pe.pop(letter_12))`
```

**Here is the Error I got**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Syed Abdul-Muqeet\OneDrive\Desktop\Files\Coding\Python_Programs\Password generator.py", line 25, in <module>

- pe.pop(letter_11) + pe.pop(letter_12))
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  IndexError: pop index out of range

I was expecting it to work just fine, but It was saying that the **Pop index was out of range**. I still don't completely understand what out of range is referring to. Is it referring to the index of the item in the list, because if that was the case it should be working fine. I am very confused, please help me. I used **pe.**len**()** to pick a random integer.

Comment: Side note: `pe.__len__()` is more conventionally written `len(pe)`

Comment: Also, all your `letter n` variables are a sure sign that you should have used a list instead.

Answer (score 2):

A much easier way to do this would be to shuffle the list and then take the first twelve characters.

```
random.shuffle(pe)
print(''.join(pe[:12]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll make sure to use this. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

yes, because after poping an element, every other after see their index reduced by one, you have to pop them after sorting them from greatest to smallest

for example, imagine a list (0,1,2,3,4,5,6) and you want to remove 3 and 4, if I pop the index 3 and then the index 4, the list will become (0,1,2,4,5,6), so the index 4 is not 4 anymore but 5, and you'll end up having (0,1,2,4,6) and not (0,1,2,5,6)

a way to avoid that is to sort the index you want to remove from the biggest to the smallest, so that when you remove the biggest index, the other you want to remove do not "move"

Comment: _because after poping an element ..._ Even before popping, `letter_1` can be out of range, because `randint()` **includes** the second endpoint as a possible value.  If you call `randint(0,10)` it might return 10, which of course is out of range for a list with 10 items.

Comment: Thank you very much! This really Helps !